# Ungrouping data frame - R

Tags: r, group-by, group

I have the following DF:

```
df <- data.frame(Type  = c("A", "A", "B"),
                 Day = c(1, 1, 1),
                 Hour = c(1,2,1),
                 Amount = c(2,3,2))

Type   Day   Hour   Amount
   A     1      1        2
   A     1      2        3
   B     1      1        2
```

And would like to end up with a DF with a number of rows equal to the sum of Amount, like this:

```
Type   Day   Hour   
   A     1      1        
   A     1      1        
   A     1      2        
   A     1      2        
   A     1      2        
   B     1      1        
   B     1      1
```

In fact is "just" an ungroup. But I've been trying to find a function that does that and couldn't find anything. There's one in dplyr but it must be used after the group one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `uncount()` function from the package `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% uncount(Amount)

  Type Day Hour
1    A   1    1
2    A   1    1
3    A   1    2
4    A   1    2
5    A   1    2
6    B   1    1
7    B   1    1
```

Comment: I googled this question for two hours, and coming here I have an answer in 1 minute. Thanks @benson23!

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R` with `rep`

```
df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$Amount),]
```